# Accordion Inside of Carousel positioning Twitter Bootstrap-3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an accordion which I am placing inside of a carousel, it works fine but I cannot seem to get the position of the header to stay and the footer to be relative(it pushes upwards, rather than opening downward) if anyone has any clue please let me know(text is dummy text and will be replaced so ignore that please) I have tried changing the header position to absolute but it does nothing, and am not seeing anything regarding elemental inheritance that should be causing this, thank you!

Bootstrap Libraries:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
        <div class="row">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="assets/img/a100Logo.png" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                   <p class="headerLightBG">Sample Training Sessions</p>
                    <p class="textLightBG">
                        Beginning Front-End Web Development<br />
                        Introduction to Programming<br />
                        Intermediate Front-End Web Development: Web Applications<br />
                        Rapid Prototyping and Iterative Development <br />
                        Advanced Front-End Web Development: Mobile/Responsive Design <br />
                        Mobile Application Development: iOS/Android <br />
                    </p>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="assets/img/a100Logo.png" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p class="headerLightBG">Sample Projects</p>
                <p class="textLightBG">
                    Write a program that successfully interacts with a commercial API.<br />
                    Create a dynamic front end for an iPhone or Android app.<br />
                    Design an engaging new web site for a technology company.<br />
                    Create a database system for matching Apprentices to Companies.<br />
                    Create a web application that allows consumers to locate fresh produce nearby.<br />
                </p>                       </div>

                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="assets/img/a100Logo.png" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
```

```
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class= "rightMargin">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                        <div class= "panel panel-default">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#FaqCost">
                                <div class= "panel-heading textLightBG headingColor">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title fatFont">
                                    Does A100 cost me anything?
                                    </h4>

                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="FaqCost">
                                <div class= "panel-body accText textDarkBG">
                                    No! The program is completely free to Apprentices. This is because A100 is an initiative of Independent Software, with support from Connecticut Innovations and our Partner Companies.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class= "panel panel-default">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#FaqTime">
                                <div class= "panel-heading textLightBG headingColor">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title fatFont">
                                            What kind of time commitment does A100 require?
                                        </h4>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="FaqTime">
                                    <div class= "panel-body accText textDarkBG">
                                        The A100 training program requires a commitment of about 10-15 hours per week, including time spent in training sessions. The Program runs 2.5 months and repeats every quarter. Apprentices have been successful in the Program while also maintaining a rigorous academic schedule. A strong work ethic and willingness to learn new things is expected of all Apprentices.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <div class= "panel panel-default">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#FaqSchedule">
                                    <div class= "panel-heading textLightBG headingColor">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title fatFont">
                                            What formal meeting times will I have to attend A100
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="FaqSchedule">
                                    <div class= "panel-body accText textDarkBG">
                                        <p class="textDarkBG  topMarginSmall centered">
                                    While the schedule does change quarterly to suit the needs of the current Cohort, here is a sample schedule that Apprentices in the Spring Cohort of 2014 are expected to adhere to.

                                </P>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>





                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class= "leftMargin">
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">

                        <div class= "panel panel-default">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#FaqFromMe">
                                <div class= "panel-heading textLightBG headingColor">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title fatFont">
                                        What does A100 want from me?
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="FaqFromMe">
                                <div class= "panel-body accText textDarkBG">
                                    In exchange for the training and opportunities we afford you to connect with local companies (as well as the free food!), we require that you sign an agreement to seek a paid apprenticeship at one of our Partner Companies in the month after graduating from the Program, and that you work there for at least three months. For more info, please read the full Terms and conditions of the Program.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class= "panel panel-default">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#FaqSkills">
                                <div class= "panel-heading textLightBG headingColor">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title fatFont">
                                        How much programming experience do I need to apply?
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="FaqSkills">
                                <div class= "panel-body accText textDarkBG">
                                    Basic programming skills are needed in an object-oriented language of your choice (C++, Java, Python, Scala, Ruby, PHP, etc.), as well as some familiarity with HTML and CSS. Don't worry! We use a programming challenge as part of our application process to make sure everyone begins from a good platform – so you 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class= "panel panel-default">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#FaqTeach">
                                <div class= "panel-heading textLightBG headingColor">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title fatFont">
                                        What will A100 teach me?
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="FaqTeach">
                                <div class= "panel-body accText textDarkBG">
                                    A100 will teach you how to create working software products as part of a small development team. You'll learn the LAMP stack (Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP), as well as improve your front end (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) development skills. We'll also expose you to practices used by working developers from the Connecticut tech 


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>







            <!-- END OF THE ACCORDION-->
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div><!-- carousel inner close-->
                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- carousel close-->

        </div><!-- row close-->
    </div><!-- container close-->
</section>
```

CSS:

```
    /* Accordion*/
.headingColor:hover
{
  -webkit-transition: color 1s;
      -moz-transition: color 1s;
      -ms-transition: color 1s;
      -o-transition: color 1s;
      transition: color 1s;
  color: #777;
}
.panel-heading a,
.panel-heading a:focus, .headingColor {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #006496;

}
.accText
{
  Background: #006496;
}
.unstyledList
{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.fatFont{
      font-weight: 600;
}
```

This is part of a much larger website, but this is the only section affected, and the accordion looks like it works fine when not placed within the carousel, perhaps that is just an issue of relative movement that the carousel brings to the users attention(I am very new to bootstrap), if so please let me know if this is impossible to fix

thanks!

Comment: to be clear: the header(class="panel-heading") slides upward to reveal the accordion content, rather than the content(class="panel-body") sliding down as it normally does

Comment: Can you also make a codepen with all your code? http://codepen.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

panel heading and body needed to have overflow hidden tricks done to them